# Access JWT access_token_cookie with javascript

Tags: python, http, flask, jwt

I have set up a JWT authentication system for my web application, however I have run into issues whilst trying to implement CSRF protection.

I am POST(ing) the data with the X-CSRF-TOKEN.

```
    let request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $form.serialize(),
        headers: {
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": json_form["csrf_token"],
            "Authorization": authHeader
        }
    })
```

*(json_form: form data converted to json obj)*

However I dont know how to access the access_token_cookie.

The HTTP request contains this cookie, however `document.cookie` does not, I assume this is because the JWT is not sent as part of the response?

My question then is this: **how does one access the JWT?**

I assumed it would be a matter of accessing this cookie straight from the browser with JS.

Otherwise maybe I could send the JWT as a header with each response, but I have a sneaking suspicion that is `superfluous()`.

My gratitude in advance.